# android Notification AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

i want to make a small notification program and i get this error 
pleas any one can help i need it for my project

```
11-19 23:42:40.297 5971-5971/com.example.codeiv.ewtest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.example.codeiv.ewtest, PID: 5971
                                                                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid notification (no valid small icon): Notification(pri=0 contentView=com.example.codeiv.ewtest/0x1090085 vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x0 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)
                                                                         at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:222)
                                                                         at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:194)
                                                                         at com.example.codeiv.ewtest.main_menu.test1(main_menu.java:54)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

11-19 23:42:42.658 5971-5971/com.example.codeiv.ewtest I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5971 SIG: 9

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
}

public void inf(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this , nfo.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public  void test1(View view){
    int mId=1;
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("My notification")
                    .setContentText("Hello World!");
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, nfo.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(nfo.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());

    mId++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set an icon for the notitification (you can use android studio default icon for testing) and make sure your button onClick method name i.e. test1() is the same as the name your set in the button's attributes properties.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("My notification")
                .setContentText("Hello World!");
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.cast_ic_notification_0)
```